# Test Twitter and Facebook sharing on a development site

Tags: facebook, twitter, share, development-environment

I want to see how sharing on my dev site is going to look on Facebook, Twitter, and Pinterest (I've added OG tags).

I know it's an oxymoron trying to test social sharing of a non-public site. But is there any way to do quality assurance of sharing before it is deployed to production? My dev URL is localhost but I do have a QA URL that is public but requires authentication.

I feel like I should be looking at this differently but I am not sure how. Must I wait until it's all live in production?

Comment: For those sites to be able to read your OG meta tags, the URLs must be publicly available via HTTP/HTTPS. (Or you need to except them from the authentication, by checking the User Agent header their scrapers send with their requests. Still requires the server itself to be reachable from the outside.)

Comment: Hmm, setting an auth exemption for sharing service bots could work. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Maybe here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569892/how-to-test-open-graph-on-localhost)

Comment: Those are great suggestions @SaïdMezhoud! I'll have to check out ngRock and ProxyLocal.